# Variables in Bourbon size() mixin

Tags: css, variables, sass, bourbon

I've recently started using an updated version of the Bourbon SASS plugin. I've previously used a custom mixin to set the `width` and `height` using the following syntax;

```
$width: 350;
$height: 200;

.wrapper {
    @include size($width $height);
}
```

This would assume `px` as the unit of measurement. However with the updated version of Bourbon, it has it's own [`size()`](http://bourbon.io/docs/#size) mixin which doesn't work quite the same.

I cannot figure out how to use variables for the width and height properties. I've tried the following to no avail;

`@include size(#{$width}px #{$height}px);` - interpolation doesn't appear to work directly in the mixin. I tried doing something similar by making a new variable that had the unit on the end.

```
$width: 350;
$height: 200;

$width_str: #{$width}px;
$height_str: #{$height}px;

.wrapper {
    @include size($width_str $height_str);
}
```

Finally, I tried setting the variables like this as I've used similar syntax elsewhere (albeit not for a mixin);

```
$width_str: ($width) + px;
$height_str: ($height) + px;
```

I don't get any errors when compiling the `SCSS`, instead the width and heigth properties are just missing from the stylesheet. I can confirm that using string values like so: `@include size(350px 200px);` does work, I just cannot get variables to play nice with this mixin. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** While I still can't get the bourbon size mixin to work with variables, I can still use the custom one I was using previously, as long as that's defined after including bourbon in my project. For reference, this is the size mixin I use, works with everything I've ever thrown at it;

```
@mixin size($size) {
    @if length($size) == 1 {
        @if $size == auto {
            width:  $size;
            height: $size;
        }

        @else if unitless($size) {
            width:  $size + px;
            height: $size + px;
        }

        @else if not(unitless($size)) {
            width:  $size;
            height: $size;
        }
    }

    // Width x Height
    @if length($size) == 2 {
        $width:  nth($size, 1);
        $height: nth($size, 2);

        @if $width == auto {
            width: $width;
        }
        @else if not(unitless($width)) {
            width: $width;
        }
        @else if unitless($width) {
            width: $width + px;
        }

        @if $height == auto {
            height: $height;
        }
        @else if not(unitless($height)) {
            height: $height;
        }
        @else if unitless($height) {
            height: $height + px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the down vote. As far as I can tell this is a perfectly valid question...?

Answer (score 1):

In the code of new Bourbone library you can find the following code for the "size" mixin:

```
@if $height == auto or (type-of($height) == number and not unitless($height)) {
  height: $height;
}

@if $width == auto or (type-of($width) == number and not unitless($width)) {
  width: $width;
}
```

The main problem is about "unitless" function that returns:

```
unitless(100) => true
unitless(100px) => false
```

that's why you have to always pass into the mixin values such as "350px", "250px"

You can try to use the following "size" mixin%

```
@mixin size($size) {
  $height: nth($size, 1);
  $width: $height;

  @if length($size) > 1 {
    $height: nth($size, 2);
  }

  @if $height == auto or type-of($height) == number {
    @if unitless($height){
      height: ($height) + px;
    } @else {
      height: $height;
    }
  }

  @if $width == auto or type-of($width) == number  {
    @if unitless($width){
      height: ($width) + px;
    } @else {
      height: $width;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does that mean, as it is the Bourbon `size` mixin cannot handle variable inputs?

Comment: I have updated the answer, i think, it is the only way to use this mixin in your case.

Comment: That mixin gives me the error: `Syntax error: $number: "auto" is not a number for 'unitless'
        on line 35 of _mixins.scss, in 'size'` when compiling. Which is the final `@if unitless($width){` line. However I have found a work around for my issue. If I save my variables 300 and 250 with `px` on the end I can still do calculations on them (which is why I needed them as variables in the first place). This means I can pass the variables in directly with `px`. Thanks for the help anyway though +1 for that.